# 2.8 Measuring tool on angles - no decimal on degrees

Tags: 3d-view

Tried different platforms and relases, and some YT videos says the same to me:
- In the version 2.7 the measure tool was hided like discouraged but on angles showed 2 decimals after the angle, so I measured with a certain precision (like 12.76°)
- In the version 2.82 the measure tool is presented in the main bar, but when I measure an angle the precision is something embarrassing, no decimal point after the entire part... (so the precedent angle will be 12° or 13°).

This change is a wanted behavior (and so... why?) or a bug?

Comment: Hi! Did you found a way to show decimals in degrees?

Comment: You can use MeasureIt addon which is available in Blender 2.8 itself